# "Extraneous Property" and "Parser Mismatched Metadata" errors in the Facebook debug validator

Tags: facebook, meta-tags, twitter-card

I am working on refactoring of one older page and I have problem with [Facebook debug validator](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/).

> Extraneous Property
> Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'twitter:card'.
>
> Extraneous Property
> Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'twitter:title'.
>
> Extraneous Property
> Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'twitter:description'.
>
> Parser Mismatched Metadata
> The parser's result for this metadata did not match the input metadata. Likely, this was caused by the data being ordered in an unexpected way, multiple values being given for a property only expecting a single value, or property values for a given property being mismatched. Here are the input properties that were not seen in the parsed result: 'twitter:card, twitter:title, twitter:description'

Should these tags has any importance? Or how I can repair it?

Comment: Give us the URL you are debugging here, otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: Ah, sorry. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zazitky.cz

Comment: As long as it only complains about the twitter properties, I think you can ignore that.

Comment: And if i want to fix it? How i can remove these warnings?

Comment: Dunno, never used that twitter stuff much myself. Maybe switching from `<meta property="twitter:card"` to `<meta name="twitter:card"` (so `name` instead of `property` on all those twitter-related tags) could help, but I am not sure ...

Comment: Thanks! Now there arent these errors, but it shows new ones. You can see it with same link (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zazitky.cz)

Comment: Now I see it only complaining about the image size. That can usually be fixed, if you scrape the image URL itself a few times.